# Cisco Anyconnect via OpenVPN tunnel on Windows

Tags: windows-7, vpn, openvpn, cisco-vpn, anyconnect

I'm trying to connect to a Cisco VPN using an USB-tethered connection using OpenVPN. The moment I enable Cisco AnyConnect, traffic stops on OpenVPN interface, resulting in disconnection.

OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

I believe AnyConnect will change the default gateway, so all traffic goes through it (i.e., the default behavior is not to do split routing).  In that case, you may no longer be able to reach your OpenVPN server if the AnyConnect destination disallows that traffic.

Comment: isn't it possible to tweak priorities, routing and such to make it work somehow? it can be completely manual, i don't expect to use such a contrived combination often.

unfortunately i can't provide more details (like `route -n`) now, that'll have to wait till tomorrow.

Comment: The term of art is apparenlty "split tunneling".  I don't know if that's pushed by the VPN server.  You should be able to do something on the client configuration.  Google for "cisco anyconnect split tunnel"?